# How do you wire a 250 volt plug when you need 240 volt power for a hot water heater

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker, water-heater, 240v

I have a 50 breaker/ plug in a temporary RV power source. The hot water heater I have needs 240 volt. How do I connect the wires on the 50 amp plug so that it runs the 240 volt needed for the hot water heater

Comment: Seriously, you should consider hiring a licensed electrician.

Comment: Why are you trying to plug a hot water heater in to begin with?

Comment: Too many unknowns. What are the specs on the water heater - rated Watts, specified breaker size? Is this temporary or permanent? Is this to share with the RV or to replace the RV?

Comment: We need _many_ more details to be able to offer _safe_ advice! Please [edit] your post to include clear, focused pictures of the manufacturer plate on the hot water heater. Also, details on how/why you suddenly need power for the hot water heater but didn't have it before would be helpful - are you switching from a gas heater?

Comment: You are looking at the max voltage on the plug. The NEC refers to things usually by what we call nominal voltage for 3 phase “high voltage” the plugs will be 480 but the NEC lists as 460. Depending where you live you may have 220v or 240 leg to leg on a split service as used un the US we call this 240v but the plug is listed 250v. Most hot water heaters are 30 amp devices and as a permanent device are not allowed to be cord and plug connected. Water heaters are usually 220-250 v devises with no neutral required a 3 wire connection.